Why Are We the Way We Are? Is Anything Real, or Could Everything Be Different?
Lately, I’ve been caught up in some pretty intense thoughts about existence. Why are we humans, with this specific form? Why do we have two hands, two eyes, and all these features that seem so perfectly suited to our environment? Why do the laws of physics work the way they do — could they have been different? Everything about life feels like it could have turned out in so many different ways. So why is it this way? Why is this reality the one we experience?
It’s a bit overwhelming sometimes, especially when you think about how the universe could have unfolded in so many different ways. Some philosophers call it “contingency,” the idea that everything that exists might have been different if just one small thing in the past had changed. We exist the way we do because of an incredibly specific set of circumstances, whether it's the random chance of evolution, the fine-tuning of physical constants in the universe, or the big bang. But why this particular set of circumstances? Why these physical laws, and not others? What if we lived in a universe where everything was completely different?
Then there’s the fact that we’re conscious, aware that we exist in the first place. It’s weird to think about how our consciousness can even grasp the vastness of the universe, or how we can ponder things like this at all. Sometimes I find myself wondering if this whole experience — the world, our bodies, everything — is even real or if we’re just some weird simulation, or a dream. I know this sounds crazy, but it can be hard not to question everything when you step back and think about how unlikely it all is.
Some ideas like the anthropic principle suggest that we’re here because the universe is "fine-tuned" to allow life, but is that a sign of purpose, or just the result of pure chance? Is life as we know it the only way it could be? And if the laws of physics and life are just a product of random events, then does any of this even matter?
These thoughts can get pretty overwhelming, honestly. Sometimes I feel like I’m lost in this vast web of existence and can’t find a clear answer to why anything is the way it is.
I’m curious if anyone else has felt this way or thought about it. Do you think any of this is “real,” or is everything just a series of accidents? Are we really here for a purpose, or are we just the product of a universe that happens to have life?

Consider looking in to Nonduality.

This question needs focus.  As it reads now it's simply expressing the existential angst that fuels humanity's search for answers to the age-old "what's the meaning of life?" question.


Why are we humans, with this specific form? Why do we have two hands, two eyes, and all these features that seem so perfectly suited to our environment? Why do the laws of physics work the way they do — could they have been different? Everything about life feels like it could have turned out in so many different ways. So why is it this way? Why is this reality the one we experience?

The laws of physics just are what they are. We seem so suited to our environment because we are, by process of evolution - if we weren’t suited, we wouldn’t survive. That answer often isn’t sufficient, though.
Let’s do a thought experiment. Suppose that things were different - suppose that instead of humans, we were the race of impossibly-huge dragons in some realm of fantasy. Would your train of thought be any different?
No matter what the Universe contains, it is what the one Universe contains. No matter the contents of the Universe, any sapient organism can perfectly-well ask the question “why is everything as it is and not some other way?”. Logically, any being asking “why is it X and not Y” could very well have grown up in a world where Y, and instead asked the question “why is it Y and not X”.
There are occasionally debates about Universal fine tuning, though this argument also applies. In the physics POV, there is likely something that requires the constants and laws to all be what they are - we simply have yet to find it.
